# Sinon + Backbone spec failing under Jasmine Headless Webkit but passing with standalone Jasmine

Tags: backbone.js, jasmine, sinon

I have a Backbone collection spec (todos, of course) that uses Sinon to fake the server response with fixture data. This passes with standalone Jasmine but fails under my Jasmine Headless Webkit setup.

The failure is this:

```
Todos collection when fetching models from the server should parse todos from the response.

  Expected 0 to equal 2. (line ~58)
    expect(this.todos.length).toEqual(this.fixture.response.todos.length);
```

Sinon and my fixture properly return a fake reposonse with 2 todos, but no todos are parsed in the collection.

There is a fiddle showing all of this working with Jasmine standalone [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kaL5d/)

My Jasmine Headless Webkit load order is as follows:

```
clyde:backbone-jasmine andy$ jasmine-headless-webkit -l
/Users/andy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jasmine-core-1.1.0/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js
/Users/andy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jasmine-core-1.1.0/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js
/Users/andy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jasmine-core-1.1.0/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css
/Users/andy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jasmine-headless-webkit-0.8.4/vendor/assets/javascripts/jasmine-extensions.js
/Users/andy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jasmine-headless-webkit-0.8.4/vendor/assets/javascripts/intense.js
/Users/andy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jasmine-headless-webkit-0.8.4/vendor/assets/javascripts/headless_reporter_result.js
/Users/andy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jasmine-headless-webkit-0.8.4/vendor/assets/javascripts/jasmine.HeadlessConsoleReporter.js
/Users/andy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jasmine-headless-webkit-0.8.4/vendor/assets/javascripts/jsDump.js
/Users/andy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jasmine-headless-webkit-0.8.4/vendor/assets/javascripts/beautify-html.js
/Users/andy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jquery-rails-2.0.2/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery.js
/Users/andy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jquery-rails-2.0.2/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js
/Users/andy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jasmine-core-1.1.0/lib/jasmine-core/json2.js
/Users/andy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/backbone-rails-0.9.2/vendor/assets/javascripts/underscore.js
/Users/andy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/backbone-rails-0.9.2/vendor/assets/javascripts/backbone.js
/Users/andy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/backbone-rails-0.9.2/vendor/assets/javascripts/backbone-rails.js
/Users/andy/Code/backbone-jasmine/app/assets/javascripts/app/collections/todos.js.coffee
/Users/andy/Code/backbone-jasmine/app/assets/javascripts/app/models/todo.js.coffee
/Users/andy/Code/backbone-jasmine/app/assets/javascripts/application.js
/Users/andy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jasmine-spec-extras-0.0.2/vendor/assets/javascripts/jasmine-jquery.js
/Users/andy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jasmine-spec-extras-0.0.2/vendor/assets/javascripts/sinon.js
/Users/andy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jasmine-spec-extras-0.0.2/vendor/assets/javascripts/jasmine-sinon.js
/Users/andy/Code/backbone-jasmine/spec/javascripts/helpers/spec_helper.js.coffee
/Users/andy/Code/backbone-jasmine/spec/javascripts/helpers/valid_response.js.coffee
/Users/andy/Code/backbone-jasmine/spec/javascripts/fixtures/todos_fixture.js.coffee
/Users/andy/Code/backbone-jasmine/spec/javascripts/app/models/todo_spec.js.coffee
/Users/andy/Code/backbone-jasmine/spec/javascripts/app/collections/todos_spec.js.coffee
```

And the code (also in the fiddle of course):

```
# abbreviated todo model
class window.Todo extends Backbone.Model


# complete todos collection
class window.Todos extends Backbone.Collection
  model: window.Todo
  url: "/todos"
  comparator: (todo) ->
    todo.get('priority')
  parse: (res) ->
    res.response.todos


# spec/javascripts/fixtures/todos_fixture.js.coffee
beforeEach ->
  @fixtures = Todos:
    valid:
      status: "OK"
      version: "1.0"
      response:
        todos: [
          id: 1
          title: "Paint the fence"
        ,
          id: 2
          title: "Wash the dog"
         ]


# spec/javascripts/helpers/valid_response.js.coffee
beforeEach ->
  @validResponse = (responseText) ->
    [ 200, "Content-Type": "application/json",
      JSON.stringify responseText ]


# abbreviated todo spec (full spec in fiddle)
describe "Todos collection", ->

  describe "when fetching models from the server", ->
    beforeEach ->
      @todo = sinon.stub(window, "Todo")
      @todos = new Todos()
      @fixture = @fixtures.Todos.valid
      @server = sinon.fakeServer.create()
      @server.respondWith "GET", "/todos", @validResponse(@fixture)

    afterEach ->
      @server.restore()
      @todo.restore()

    it "should parse todos from the response", ->
      @todos.fetch()
      @server.respond()
      expect(@todos.length).toEqual @fixture.response.todos.length
      expect(@todos.get(1).get('title')).toEqual @fixture.response.todos[0].title
```

Several of the tools being used are new to me so I really appreciate any help-- thanks!!

Comment: fyi, i've been able to recreate this.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is something asynchronous happening in `server.respond()`.
Have you tried this?

```
it "should parse todos from the response", ->
  @todos.fetch()
  @server.respond()
  waits 500
  runs ->
    expect(@todos.length).toEqual @fixture.response.todos.length
    expect(@todos.get(1).get('title')).toEqual @fixture.response.todos[0].title
```